# JVM OutOfMemory - requested 8589934608 bytes for Chunk::new. Out of swap space?

Tags: windows, tomcat, jvm, out-of-memory, swap

In my company we develop an enterprise web application in Spring (Flex frontend) and deploy this app to our customers in Tomcat 7 in SAAS style.

Recently we are suffering from (seemingly) random OutOfMemory errors that we see in out stderr log file:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

This issue happens with different configurations of memory, the one that was configured when we saw this error was as follows:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 8589934608 bytes for Chunk::new. Out of swap space?
#
#  Internal Error (allocation.cpp:215), pid=1184, tid=1692
#  Error: Chunk::new
#
# JRE version: 6.0_18-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (16.0-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 )
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000005864800):  JavaThread "CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1692, stack(0x0000000005d00000,0x0000000005e00000)]

Stack: [0x0000000005d00000,0x0000000005e00000]

Current CompileTask:
C2:6164  !   org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.serveResource(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Z)V (1261 bytes)


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000006569000 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-1007" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2876, stack(0x000000000f800000,0x000000000f900000)]
  0x000000000656a800 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-1006" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4012, stack(0x000000000ef80000,0x000000000f080000)]
  0x000000000656a000 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-1005" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4068, stack(0x000000000ec00000,0x000000000ed00000)]
  0x000000000656c000 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-1004" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2852, stack(0x000000000eb00000,0x000000000ec00000)]
  0x0000000008a29800 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-1003" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1796, stack(0x000000000ea00000,0x000000000eb00000)]
  0x0000000008a2a000 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-1002" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=792, stack(0x000000000e800000,0x000000000e900000)]
  0x0000000008a28000 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-1001" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3624, stack(0x000000000e600000,0x000000000e700000)]
  0x0000000008a27000 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-1000" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=468, stack(0x000000000e500000,0x000000000e600000)]
  0x0000000008a2d000 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-999" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1436, stack(0x000000000cb60000,0x000000000cc60000)]
  0x0000000006567000 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-998" daemon [_thread_in_Java, id=3520, stack(0x00000000084d0000,0x00000000085d0000)]
  0x0000000006bb0800 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-993" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1848, stack(0x000000000f500000,0x000000000f600000)]
  0x0000000006bb1800 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-992" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2944, stack(0x000000000f300000,0x000000000f400000)]
  0x0000000006bb4800 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-989" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3092, stack(0x000000000cc60000,0x000000000cd60000)]
  0x0000000006bb2800 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-987" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3676, stack(0x000000000f700000,0x000000000f800000)]
  0x0000000008a2c000 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-981" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=668, stack(0x000000000e700000,0x000000000e800000)]
  0x0000000006568800 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-971" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3664, stack(0x0000000000b30000,0x0000000000c30000)]
  0x000000000b0e6800 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-928" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3760, stack(0x000000000f600000,0x000000000f700000)]
  0x0000000006baf000 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-892" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4080, stack(0x000000000e900000,0x000000000ea00000)]
  0x0000000008a26800 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=624, stack(0x000000000f400000,0x000000000f500000)]
  0x0000000008a2a800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1476, stack(0x000000000f100000,0x000000000f200000)]
  0x0000000008a28800 JavaThread "scheduler-2" [_thread_blocked, id=3036, stack(0x00000000083d0000,0x00000000084d0000)]
  0x000000000b0e0800 JavaThread "ajp-bio-8009-AsyncTimeout" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2588, stack(0x000000000e400000,0x000000000e500000)]
  0x000000000b0e0000 JavaThread "ajp-bio-8009-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2584, stack(0x000000000d260000,0x000000000d360000)]
  0x000000000b0df800 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-AsyncTimeout" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2580, stack(0x000000000d160000,0x000000000d260000)]
  0x0000000008fdf800 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2576, stack(0x000000000d060000,0x000000000d160000)]
  0x0000000008fdc800 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-AsyncTimeout" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2572, stack(0x000000000cf60000,0x000000000d060000)]
  0x0000000008fde000 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2568, stack(0x000000000ce60000,0x000000000cf60000)]
  0x0000000008fdd800 JavaThread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2564, stack(0x000000000cd60000,0x000000000ce60000)]
  0x0000000008fdf000 JavaThread "scheduler-1" [_thread_blocked, id=2536, stack(0x0000000000c30000,0x0000000000d30000)]
  0x0000000008fda800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rxcpk971gv269anlzvh0|79a422d9]-HelperThread-#19" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2476, stack(0x000000000ca60000,0x000000000cb60000)]
  0x0000000008fd9800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rxcpk971gv269anlzvh0|79a422d9]-HelperThread-#18" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2472, stack(0x000000000c960000,0x000000000ca60000)]
  0x0000000008fd9000 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rxcpk971gv269anlzvh0|79a422d9]-HelperThread-#17" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2468, stack(0x000000000c860000,0x000000000c960000)]
  0x0000000008fd8800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rxcpk971gv269anlzvh0|79a422d9]-HelperThread-#16" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2464, stack(0x000000000c760000,0x000000000c860000)]
  0x0000000008fd7800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rxcpk971gv269anlzvh0|79a422d9]-HelperThread-#15" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2460, stack(0x000000000c660000,0x000000000c760000)]
  0x0000000008fd7000 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rxcpk971gv269anlzvh0|79a422d9]-HelperThread-#14" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2456, stack(0x000000000c560000,0x000000000c660000)]
  0x0000000008fd6000 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rxcpk971gv269anlzvh0|79a422d9]-HelperThread-#13" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2452, stack(0x000000000c460000,0x000000000c560000)]
  0x0000000008fd5800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rxcpk971gv269anlzvh0|79a422d9]-HelperThread-#12" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2448, stack(0x000000000c360000,0x000000000c460000)]
  0x0000000008fd4800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rxcpk971gv269anlzvh0|79a422d9]-HelperThread-#11" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2444, stack(0x000000000c260000,0x000000000c360000)]
  0x0000000008fd4000 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rxcpk971gv269anlzvh0|79a422d9]-HelperThread-#10" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2440, stack(0x000000000c160000,0x000000000c260000)]
  0x0000000008fd3000 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rxcpk971gv269anlzvh0|79a422d9]-HelperThread-#9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2436, stack(0x000000000c060000,0x000000000c160000)]
  0x0000000008fd2800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rxcpk971gv269anlzvh0|79a422d9]-HelperThread-#8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2432, stack(0x000000000bf60000,0x000000000c060000)]
  0x0000000008fd2000 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rxcpk971gv269anlzvh0|79a422d9]-HelperThread-#7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2428, stack(0x000000000be60000,0x000000000bf60000)]
  0x0000000008fd1000 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rxcpk971gv269anlzvh0|79a422d9]-HelperThread-#6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2424, stack(0x000000000bd60000,0x000000000be60000)]
  0x00000000059d4800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rxcpk971gv269anlzvh0|79a422d9]-HelperThread-#5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2420, stack(0x000000000bc60000,0x000000000bd60000)]
  0x00000000059d3800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rxcpk971gv269anlzvh0|79a422d9]-HelperThread-#4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2416, stack(0x000000000bb60000,0x000000000bc60000)]
  0x00000000066b1800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rxcpk971gv269anlzvh0|79a422d9]-HelperThread-#3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2412, stack(0x0000000009aa0000,0x0000000009ba0000)]
  0x000000000682b000 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rxcpk971gv269anlzvh0|79a422d9]-HelperThread-#2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2408, stack(0x00000000099a0000,0x0000000009aa0000)]
  0x000000000668a000 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rxcpk971gv269anlzvh0|79a422d9]-HelperThread-#1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2404, stack(0x00000000098a0000,0x00000000099a0000)]
  0x000000000872b000 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rxcpk971gv269anlzvh0|79a422d9]-HelperThread-#0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2400, stack(0x00000000097a0000,0x00000000098a0000)]
  0x0000000006727800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rxcpk971gv269anlzvh0|79a422d9]-AdminTaskTimer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2396, stack(0x00000000096a0000,0x00000000097a0000)]
  0x000000000629e800 JavaThread "Thread-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2292, stack(0x00000000085d0000,0x00000000086d0000)]
  0x00000000059b4000 JavaThread "GC Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2216, stack(0x0000000006c00000,0x0000000006d00000)]
  0x0000000005866800 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1700, stack(0x0000000005e00000,0x0000000005f00000)]
=>0x0000000005864800 JavaThread "CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1692, stack(0x0000000005d00000,0x0000000005e00000)]
  0x0000000005859800 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1680, stack(0x0000000005c00000,0x0000000005d00000)]
  0x0000000005856800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1672, stack(0x0000000005b00000,0x0000000005c00000)]
  0x0000000005851800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1668, stack(0x0000000005a00000,0x0000000005b00000)]
  0x0000000000473000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1516, stack(0x0000000005700000,0x0000000005800000)]
  0x0000000000472000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1508, stack(0x0000000005600000,0x0000000005700000)]
  0x000000000037c800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=1376, stack(0x0000000000f30000,0x0000000001030000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000000000046d000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000005500000,0x0000000005600000] [id=1492]
  0x0000000005867800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000005f00000,0x0000000006000000] [id=1704]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 674624K, used 270750K [0x0000000115550000, 0x000000013fff0000, 0x000000013fff0000)
  eden space 649152K, 40% used [0x0000000115550000,0x0000000125927478,0x000000013cf40000)
  from space 25472K, 18% used [0x000000013e710000,0x000000013eba0578,0x000000013fff0000)
  to   space 24384K, 0% used [0x000000013cf40000,0x000000013cf40000,0x000000013e710000)
 PSOldGen        total 1398144K, used 1102711K [0x00000000bfff0000, 0x0000000115550000, 0x0000000115550000)
  object space 1398144K, 78% used [0x00000000bfff0000,0x00000001034cdd10,0x0000000115550000)
 PSPermGen       total 1048576K, used 214588K [0x000000007fff0000, 0x00000000bfff0000, 0x00000000bfff0000)
  object space 1048576K, 20% used [0x000000007fff0000,0x000000008d17f088,0x00000000bfff0000)

Dynamic libraries:
0x0000000140000000 - 0x000000014001c000     C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\Tomcat7.exe
0x00000000770f0000 - 0x0000000077299000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000076ed0000 - 0x0000000076fef000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefd010000 - 0x000007fefd07c000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x000007fefd3b0000 - 0x000007fefd48b000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefeb20000 - 0x000007fefebbf000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007fefd910000 - 0x000007fefd92f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefd930000 - 0x000007fefda5d000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x000007fefdc70000 - 0x000007fefe9f8000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x000007fefd890000 - 0x000007fefd901000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007fefd340000 - 0x000007fefd3a7000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x0000000076ff0000 - 0x00000000770ea000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007fefee70000 - 0x000007fefee7e000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007fefd270000 - 0x000007fefd339000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefd810000 - 0x000007fefd83e000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefee90000 - 0x000007fefef99000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x000000006d7f0000 - 0x000000006de95000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fef9900000 - 0x000007fef993b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x000000006d760000 - 0x000000006d76e000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\verify.dll
0x000000006d3b0000 - 0x000000006d3d7000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.dll
0x000000006d310000 - 0x000000006d31a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\hpi.dll
0x00000000772c0000 - 0x00000000772c7000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x000000006d7b0000 - 0x000000006d7c2000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefda60000 - 0x000007fefdc63000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x000000006d540000 - 0x000000006d54a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\management.dll
0x000000006d600000 - 0x000000006d617000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\net.dll
0x000007fefd840000 - 0x000007fefd88d000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefee80000 - 0x000007fefee88000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fefc650000 - 0x000007fefc6a5000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefc640000 - 0x000007fefc647000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x000007fefc050000 - 0x000007fefc057000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x000007fefc6b0000 - 0x000007fefc6c7000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x000007fefc3b0000 - 0x000007fefc3f7000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x000007fefceb0000 - 0x000007fefcebf000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x000007fefcd10000 - 0x000007fefcd1f000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x000007fefbbb0000 - 0x000007fefbbc5000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x000007fef9940000 - 0x000007fef9955000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x000007fefc4d0000 - 0x000007fefc52b000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x000007fef9e40000 - 0x000007fef9e4b000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x000007fefa4a0000 - 0x000007fefa4c7000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x000007fefa3f0000 - 0x000007fefa3fb000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fef9e30000 - 0x000007fef9e38000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x000007fefa380000 - 0x000007fefa3d3000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x000000006d000000 - 0x000000006d1c2000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\awt.dll
0x000007fef84c0000 - 0x000007fef8531000     C:\Windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x000007fefb3a0000 - 0x000007fefb440000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.18201_none_a4d3b9377117c3df\COMCTL32.dll
0x000000006d2a0000 - 0x000000006d30b000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x000000006d620000 - 0x000000006d62b000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\nio.dll
0x000007fefae80000 - 0x000007fefae98000     C:\Windows\system32\DWMAPI.DLL

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0 -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\temp -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\conf\logging.properties -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0 -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\temp -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\conf\logging.properties -XX:PermSize=1024m -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 44 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 4 (1 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 44 stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt

Memory: 4k page, physical 8388088k(197084k free), swap 22991520k(8404948k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (16.0-b13) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_18-b07), built on Dec 17 2009 13:24:11 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 8.0 (VS2005)

time: Thu Feb 26 17:11:51 2015
elapsed time: 136555 seconds
```

This does not look like a "normal" OOM error since it does not trigger the saving of a heap dump, looks something more like it is triggered by the OS.
It looks strange to me that the JVM it's requesting SO MUCH memory, it's 8,5 gigs of memory, which is something similar but superior to the current paging file size configured in the OS (8191 mb)

[image]

The JVM options are as follows:

> -XX:PermSize=1024m
>   -Xms2048m
>   -Xmx2048m
>   -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

The heap and permgen space does not look full to me, what it captured my attention is this system info in the error log:

```
Memory: 4k page, physical 8388088k(197084k free), swap 22991520k(8404948k free)
```

which shows how the free swap space is in fact less than the requested one.

But why requesting so much?

The JVM is java 1.6.18

The error appear randomly when the server is stressed or when it's almost idle.

Comment: It says it's an internal JDK error. Try upgrading (at least to the newest patchset for 1.6 if JDK7 or JDK8 seem too risky).

Comment: possible duplicate of [JVM errors after updating to Java 6 Update 14](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102544/jvm-errors-after-updating-to-java-6-update-14)

Comment: This sounds very similar to this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435819/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-requested-1958536-bytes-for-chunknew-out-of-swap

Comment: Thanks @Thilo, I will definitely try to update to a new JVM (I already tried with the last version of java 6, but had other kind of problems that prevented me to perfom  a real test, I will try harder).

Comment: Ok, I succeded in updating the JVM to the last version of Java 6 (1.6.45 as of now). Now I will see if those kind of errors stop or not and eventually file an answer in the next weeks.
Thanks